# How is it grammatical that 'begrudge' admits three objects?

Tags: relative-pronouns, transitivity, direct-objects

[Source, penultimate para:](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/books/2014/06/against_ya_adults_should_be_embarrassed_to_read_children_s_books.2.html) p 2 of 2, 'Against YA', by [Ruth Graham](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/ruth-graham/23/377/848), slate.com

> 1. [I do not **begrudge** young adults themselves their renaissance of fiction.](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/books/2014/06/against_ya_adults_should_be_embarrassed_to_read_children_s_books.2.html)
>
> [begrudge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/begrudge) ***[with two objects]*** = D1. Envy (someone) the possession or enjoyment of (something)

I`m guessing D1 (D for Definition) above as the right one, but the grammar for  **begrudge** still confuses and shocks me. ODO's Example Sentnces also follow this strange construct. Would someone please elucidate and explain? I tried to replace **begrudge** with its synonym 'envy', then 1 becomes:

2. I don't **envy** young adults  themselves their renaissance of fiction.

Yet 2 is ungrammatical, because it involves 3 objects and no prepositions? Instead, you must write:

3. I don't **envy** young adults  themselves [FOR] their renaissance of fiction.

4. I don't **envy** young adults' <s>themselves their</s> renaissance of fiction.

However, now 3 and 4 differ from 1, a contradiction, so what happened?

Comment: Where did you get this quote? *themselves* is odd. It would not be a third object, but would stand in apposition to "adults".

Comment: @TRomano I think so too. Sorry for forgetting the source. Better now?

Comment: Where are the three objects? The objects are (1) young adults themselves, and (2) their renaissance of fiction.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen *themselves, himself, herself* with begrudge.  It makes little sense to me. I want to understand it as the author does begrudge somebody something, but not the young adults.

Comment: @δοῦλος I may have erred, so please feel free to edit my OP

Answer (score 2):

> We saw the children themselves.

*Saw* has one object: *the children themselves*.

> I do not begrudge young adults themselves their renaissance of fiction.

*Begrudge* has two objects: (1) young adults themselves, (2) their renaissance of fiction.

I just do not get what is confusing here.

I am not big on sticking in "synonyms" into sentences. And I do not think that is what the ODO definition means. Although *envy* itself can take two objects.

> I don't envy the young adults themselves their renaissance of fiction.

*Envy* has two objects: (1) young adults themselves, (2) their renaissance of fiction.

Comment: Don't you find the use of "themselves" there passing strange?